# How to implement a Mean Pooling layer in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

There seems no built-in support for Mean Pooling layer for RNN in Keras. Anyone knows how to wrap one?

[image]
http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html

Comment: Look at this answer, use [TemporalMeanPooling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43014228/1105231) may help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keras has a layer `AveragePooling1D` for that. If you use the graph API, you should be able to do something like:

```py
model.add_node(AveragePooling1D(...), 
               inputs=['h0', 'h1', ..., 'hn'], 
               merge_mode='concat', ...)
```

Comment: Do you have any example for Sequential model? Eg. how to connect AveragePooling1D with an RNN layer that has return_sequence enabled.

Comment: I don't have an example but it looks like should be able to just add an `AveragePooling1D` layer to your `Sequential` after the `RNN` layer and specify the correct dimension for the pooling.

Comment: @IsilmëO - since you've accepted the answer, can you show a complete example? I'm unable to follow the `AveragePooling1D` layer with a `Dense(1)` layer